# the meaning of "more to come"

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

I have just read this sentence: **"for over 400 years and more to come"**. Does the **"more to come"** in that sentence mean **"another year that's coming"** or does it mean something else?

Comment: More of what? Before this phrase, there must be something that was going on for "over 400 years"? Whatever it is, it will continue beyond the present moment.

Answer (score 1):

It means that whatever happened during that 400 years, will continue to happen for many more years.